# get subset of keys and wrap output to list using jq

Tags: json, jq

Let's assume we have the following records:

```
[
{"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2"},
{"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2"},
{"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2"}
]
```

and we want to keep only a subset of the keys such as `k1`

What operation do we have to do to get the following output?

```
[
{"k1": "v1"},
{"k1": "v1"},
{"k1": "v1"}
]
```

I've tried doing `jq '.[] | { "k1": .k1 }'` but it returns

```
{"k1": "v1"}
{"k1": "v1"}
{"k1": "v1"}
```

Also tried doing `jq '.[] | { "k1": .k1 }' | jq '[inputs]'` but for some reason it removes the first row

```
[
{"k1": "v1"},
{"k1": "v1"}
]
```

Comment: You were close. `jq '[ .[] | { "k1": .k1 } ]'`

Comment: Or, if using `inputs`, you need the `-n` argument to stop the first one from being removed (as it's consumed to become `.`). I'm *certain* we already have duplicates about that.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more in detail what the `-n` flag does?

Comment: `-n` makes `.` be `null`, not the first input read, thus leaving that first input still available in `inputs`.

Comment: BTW, if you have a nested case, that needs to be included *in the question*. In this situation, you should probably accept the answer by @oguzismail as-is (insofar as it's correct for the question you originally asked), and ask a new question that describes the set of inputs you're trying to process more comprehensively.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to read what to do [when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and then mark this and your other previously answered questions as resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `map`, it applies a filter to all elements of an array.

```
$ jq 'map({k1})' file
[
  {
    "k1": "v1"
  },
  {
    "k1": "v1"
  },
  {
    "k1": "v1"
  }
]
```